# Reducing/Collecting stream of a flattened map in particular traversing order (not Depth-first search)

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm checking everything for reducing/collecting a flattened map in my particular traverse order (not Depth-first search) and can't find an example/collectors signature for this kind of operation. I'll try to explain it with a simplified example:

I got 3 maps

```
Map1: {1,"a1"; 2, "b1"; 3, "c1"}
Map2: {1,"a2", 2, "b2"; 3, "c2"}
Map3: {1,"a3"; 2, "b3"; 3, "c3"}
```

I want to end up collecting it as following:

```
LinkedHashSet() {new LinkedHashSet("a1","a2","a3"), 
                 new LinkedHashSet("b1","b2","b3"), 
                 new LinkedHashSet("c1","c2","c3")}
```

If I use flatMap I would have something like 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 instead of 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3, so I am trying some kind of dirty grouping by, but cannot survive to all the signatures. I am trying things like this but I frankly get lost, it must be an easier approach:

```
...flatMap( map-> map.stream() )
.collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.reducing(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)))
```

(This is just a simplification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original approach isn’t so bad, but you have small errors within it. Unfortunately, current compilers have a tendency to flood the error messages with reports about generic signature mismatches, making it easy to overlook the simpler errors like methods or types that haven’t been found, which are more than often the actual cause of the problem.

First, there is no `stream()` method in `Map`. You have to decide which collection view to stream on, `keySet()`, `entrySet()` or `values()`. Obviously, you want to use `map-> map.entrySet().stream()` instead of `map-> map.stream()`.

Second, you used `Collectors.reducing` instead of the obviously intended `Collectors.mapping`.

Fixing these errors should be sufficient to let the generic signature errors go away as well; the result of the `groupingBy` collector is a `Map<Integer, LinkedHashSet<String>>` then, but unfortunately, it’s not an order maintaining map by default. Therefore, you have to add a map `Supplier`, i.e. `LinkedHashMap::new` to enforce the use of an order maintaining `Map`.

Then, you have to copy the result map’s `values()` to a `LinkedHashSet` to get a result of the desired type, i.e. `new LinkedHashSet<>(resultMap.values())`.

Putting it all together, we get:

```
Map<Integer,String> map1 = map(1,"a1", 2,"b1", 3,"c1");
Map<Integer,String> map2 = map(1,"a2", 2,"b2", 3,"c2");
Map<Integer,String> map3 = map(1,"a3", 2,"b3", 3,"c3");

Map<Integer, LinkedHashSet<String>> m = Stream.of(map1, map2, map3)
    .flatMap( map -> map.entrySet().stream() )
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
            Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))));
LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> result=new LinkedHashSet<>(m.values());
// [[a1, a2, a3], [b1, b2, b3], [c1, c2, c3]]
System.out.println(result);
```

```
static <K,V> Map<K,V> map(K k1, V v1, K k2, V v2, K k3, V v3) {
    LinkedHashMap<K,V> m=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    m.put(k1, v1);
    m.put(k2, v2);
    m.put(k3, v3);
    return m;
}
```

I hope, you still recognize your original approach within the changed code.
You can also integrate the post-processing step into the `Collector` via `collectingAndThen`:

```
LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> result = Stream.of(map1, map2, map3)
    .flatMap( map -> map.entrySet().stream() )
    .collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))),
        m -> new LinkedHashSet<>(m.values())));
```

---

It should be mentioned that this result will only look rectangular, like a transposed table of the original maps, if the values are all unique. `LinkedHashSet`, like any other `Set`, will eliminate duplicate elements. This does not only apply to the sub-sets, but also to the result set that will eliminate identical sub-sets.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly noticed by Holger I initially missed your point about traverse order.

But traverse order only makes sense if your initial Maps (`Map1, Map2, Map3`) are some instances of a Map that are ordered, like `LinkedHashMap` or a `SortedMap`.

I'll try to explain. Suppose this example (using jdk-9 new Immutable Maps - that internally use a randomization pattern, meaning that the order in which you get the entries is not guaranteed).

```
    Map<Integer, String> map1 = Map.of(3, "a1", 2, "b1", 1, "c1");
    Map<Integer, String> map2 = Map.of(3, "a2", 2, "b2", 1, "c2");
    Map<Integer, String> map3 = Map.of(3, "a3", 2, "b3", 1, "c3");

    System.out.println(Stream.of(map1, map2, map3)
           .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The result of this operation could be of of these two for example.

> [2=b1, 3=a1, 1=c1, 2=b2, 3=a2, 1=c2, 2=b3, 3=a3, 1=c3]
>
> [1=c1, 3=a1, 2=b1, 1=c2, 3=a2, 2=b2, 1=c3, 3=a3, 2=b3]

At this point in time HashMap does not have any sort of randomization done internally or any other functionality that could alter the order of the entries when iterating over it, but *it could happen* on a future release, so you can't rely on that.

Thus, assuming your maps are LinkedHashMaps:

```
Set<Set<String>> result = Stream.of(map1, map2, map3).flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> e.getKey(),
                    e -> {
                        Set<String> l = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                        l.add(e.getValue());
                        return l;
                    },
                    (left, right) -> {
                        left.addAll(right);
                        return left;
                    },
                    LinkedHashMap::new),
                    map -> map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))));
```

Comment: You should specify the supplier `LinkedHashMap::new` to the `toMap` collector, otherwise, the order might be lost before copying to the `LinkedHashSet`. Then, instead of `.entrySet() .stream() .map(e -> e.getValue())`, you can just use `.values() .stream()`. Though, I’d just use `map -> new LinkedHashSet<>(map.values())` as finishing function (`collectingAndThen`)…

Comment: @Holger you're probably right, will edit in a few min, but what if `Map1, Map2, Map3` are instances of jdk-9 `Map.of()` that implement a randomization pattern themselves? Then there would be no consistent *same* traversal, meaning you can not rely on that. Those maps would have to be LinkedHashMaps also...

Comment: The entire question makes only sense, if we assume that the source maps are ordered, e.g. either `LinkedHashMap`s or `SortedMap`s. If the source maps have no order, there is nothing you can do. To be precise, it’s the first map which must have an order for this operation to return an ordered result.

Comment: Both answers are really great! But Holger's one is a bit easier to track so I picked up sorry!!!

Comment: As a side note, even if `HashMap` doesn’t do randomization of the iteration order, the mere fact that it’s spliterator reports not to be `ORDERED` is sufficient to allow the Stream implementation to process the items in a different order than delivered by the spliterator. So even if a `HashMap` instance happens to deliver its content in a reproducible iteration order, there is no guaranty that stream operations will process the elements in that order.